# How to get involved in open-source project? (Android/java programmer)

Tags: java, open-source, android

My question might sound stupid and not suitable for this site, but i dont have any better place to ask then here, so please bear with me.

Im a college student that love playing with android. Around last year, i changed my main OS to Ubuntu, and i found its amazing. So, i decided that i want to help developing open-source project.

However, ubuntu uses C++ & QML, not java so i cant code for them. Do you know where i can find a good or widely use android open-source project?

I know i can find some projects in code.google, but theres too many project. I dont know which one is suitable/good for me.

Any help/suggestion is appreciated (im still a college student after all). And if you wondering "why dont i learn c++?", well i think i dont have enough time to learn now because i also have a part-time job as a android developer. Thats why i prever android, or at least java.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helping an open source project is a good cause, but motivation is more important. If you're coding for the sake of coding, my motivation wavers without a goal or a deep interest.  First, you must decide what is important to you, or what interests you.  Pick the field.  Then try to find an open source project based on your passion.  Usually contributing is as easy as getting the source, viewing their buglist, and getting familiar with their forums and submission guidelines.  The first accepted fix will most likely not be your first submission, so have patience, persist, and participate.